# Why is 'summary' not working on linear model of these data in R?

Tags: r

## Session Info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)


attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0 dplyr_0.4.1   plyr_1.8.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1   colorspace_1.2-4 DBI_0.3.1        digest_0.6.4     formatR_1.2      grid_3.1.2      
 [7] gtable_0.1.2     htmltools_0.2.6  httpuv_1.3.2     knitr_1.10.5     lazyeval_0.1.10  magrittr_1.5    
[13] MASS_7.3-35      mime_0.2         munsell_0.4.2    packrat_0.4.3    parallel_3.1.2   proto_0.3-10    
[19] R6_2.0.1         Rcpp_0.11.5      reshape2_1.4     RJSONIO_1.3-0    scales_0.2.4     shiny_0.11.1    
[25] stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.2      xtable_1.7-4
```

## Data set

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(variation = c(0.626815828244532, 0.545797538497282, 
0.558226439404027, 0.427647726146102, 0.391128368954833, 0.509684115559787, 
0.910678839606448, 0.976563610753248, 0.937866096144771, 0.735154713808796, 
0.91378072555531, 0.655357590199441, 0.484736678245366, 0.500997654883741, 
0.278823718665372, 0.374523873110335, 0.407675893997702, 0.330964380968588, 
0.325030234744976, 0.127511226832626, 0.244836628421321, 0.292741376601331, 
0.0968514878662283, 0.258328273581007, 0.237981711587848, 0.275356267397724, 
0.192989933630191, 0.197390726795804, 0.375494359665328, 0.148781826718284, 
0.164998369719128, 0.0131814493967959, 0.0646749934321311, 0.134988818908056, 
0.0443586579648255, 0.0260330258977941, 0.104427121628245, 0.095582182403226, 
0.0806982957427736, 0.0440387421169708, 0.0274488611364823), 
    m.gapdist = c(13.3552750177431, 13.8087579617834, 12.6852272727273, 
    22.7146339347675, 21.8546590909091, 22.4446788990826, 32.9576445058197, 
    35.0773548387097, 33.1109944751381, 42.9548010939831, 42.1741743119266, 
    41.6259210526316, 53.0552433281005, 53.2622018348624, 52.36, 
    63.1930234335201, 62.962030075188, 64.6794736842105, 73.1398024591816, 
    73.045855513308, 72.79015625, 83.5571808028977, 84.142197309417, 
    83.6761111111111, 93.6386090990863, 90.9626446280992, 94.6396673596674, 
    102.235840326061, 101.741428571429, 102.936891891892, 112.357367974549, 
    112.767, 111.384594594595, 122.350092893637, 123.592105263158, 
    121.112941176471, 132.52527589545, 130.99125, 141.686573208723, 
    152.516842105263, 160.072)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("variation", 
"m.gapdist"))
```

## Error

```
> lmfit1 <- lm(variation ~ m.gapdist ,df)
> summary(lmfit1)
Error in summary.lm(lmfit1) : unused argument (lmfit1)
```

## UPDATE

I think the problem was associated with memory. I had 9 data sets loaded eating the system memory. Once I removed all the data and loaded only few data frames, the `summary` function started working again.

Comment: Works fine on my computer, R 3.2.0. Maybe you need to try it without packages to pinpoint the bug..?

Comment: or `find("summary.lm")` ?

Comment: I get `> find("summary.lm")
[1] ".GlobalEnv"    "package:stats"`

Comment: I restarted the R session but still get same error even without loading any packages

Comment: Also works on my machine (R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18), Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit), Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS). Maybe update your R version to see if it would help?

Comment: I have installed R version 3.2.1 but still get same error even with different data sets

Comment: you need to make sure you're not re-loading a `.RData` file that contains the offending file.  You should probably find it and delete it. The fact that `.GlobalEnv` shows up first in the results of `find()` means you do have a (wonky) version of `summary.lm()` in your global workspace, masking the `stats::` one.

Comment: Your updated diagnosis is almost certainly wrong.  In the process of cleaning up the additional data frames, you coincidentally got rid of the bogus copy of `summary.lm()`.

Comment: @BenBolker That might be true. I removed the data frames before your comment so I am unsure about the real cause of error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your environment (by running `ls()`) to make sure that you have not defined a function with no arguments named "summary.lm". I find the fact that ".GlobalEnv" shows up on your search list (in first place) suspicious. The error message is consistent with R thinking that `summary.lm` takes no arguments.

Amended after reading Ben Bolker's comment: Sorry, poor use of terminology on my part. By "on your search list" I meant on the sequence that `find()` reported, not on the general search list for the R session.

Comment: `.GlobalEnv` showing up first in the search list is exactly as expected, not suspicious (try `search()` from a clean R session).  The problem is not the presence of `.GlobalEnv` in the search path, but the presence of `summary.lm` in the global environment ...